# Slim framework - Getting float from url

Tags: php, slim

I need to get a float number from url using slim framework. Here's a sample url:

```
http://analytics.xxx.com/18539523/1.2/6a15206e23de18994007ea290cce64c9445c438d/
```

Slim is getting "1.2" as "1". Is it possible to get the correct float number?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the URL is generated you might need to escape the . so it becomes %2E